# How to get the browser and Operating System name using Geb and Spock framework at runtime

Tags: spock, geb

I want to get the browser name which is currently being used to execute the test scripts and the Operating system name using Geb and Spock framework.

I want these details at runtime to append into the test report.

For example.

If test currently running in Chrome browser then I should get the chrome browser name its version and OS name at runtime

If test currently running in Firefox browser then I should get the Firefox browser name its version and OS name at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `driver.capabilities` to get the browser name,
example: `driver.capabilities['browserName']`.
A closer look at `driver.capabilities` will also show the version and driver version.

To get the operating system you can use the property `System.getProperty("os.name")`.
There are many ways to check the OS, it depends on your frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

For OS, use

System.getProperty("os.name")

For browser:

println browser.driver

Need to parse the string to get the name only

The os is in spock.util.environment.OperatingSystem